# iOS how to make a button run a code for another view controller?

Tags: ios

I can't figure out how to run code from different `View Controller`'s .

I have created a new project, and would appreciate a quick response as its homework, and have to be done by tonight.

In my project I have two `View Controller`'s named; `viewcontroller1` and `viewcontroller2`, and have assigned them to two different custom classes.

`Viewcontroller1` comes to screen it has two `UIButtons`, one for running the code, and the other one to push to `viewcontroller2`.

When user clicks the first `UIButton` I want that button to run the code below and display the results on a `UILabel` on my `viewcontroller2`.

The code creates random numbers using `arc4random` and then show's random words in the `UILabel`. The code works for single page based apps, and is used under implementation.

So basically what i want is, when i click the first `UIButton` i want to display randomly created words on my `UILabel` in the `viewcontroller2`.

```
-(IBAction)button; {
    int random_num;
    random_num = (arc4random() % 5 - 1) + 1;
    if (random_num == 1) { 
    label.text = @"hello1";    
    } 
    else if (random_num == 2) {
    label.text = @"hello2";
    }
    else if (random_num == 3) {
    label.text = @"hello3";
    }
    else if (random_num == 4) {
    label.text = @"hello4";
    }
}
```

The `timelabel` is the `UILabel` on my `viewcontroller2`.

Can you please be detailed in your answer. I am a beginner and might not grasp the concepts right away.

**Example**

User opens the app

Viewcontroller1 is shown

User press the `button 1` which runs code for the `label` in the `viewcontroller2`

User press the `button 2` to go to `viewcontroller`

`Viewcontroller2` comes up and label on it has changed by the button

I know that it is not a hard thing to do but I can't do it.

For those who answered me before and for those who will answer thank you soo much..

Thanks.

Comment: You will need some basic concepts to do this, do you know what outlets, segues and storyboard are?

Comment: yes I have some knowledge about storyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all I want to make it clear, it is not possible that viewcontroller1 comes to screen. Actually view of viewcontroller1 comes to screen. You see on the screen only the views and they belongs / controlled by viewcontrollers.

To answer you question correctly we need to know, what do you use to change the views? Do you use a navigation controller, tabbarcontroller or something else?

Commonly the labels, which is a UI element for presenting textes are initialized in viewDidLoad method of the viewcontroller. So setting text before that does nothing.

if you have reference to viewcontroller2 from viewcontroller1 you can create a property to hold the text and set it after pressing the button. And viewcontroller2 can present the text after loading the view on a label. So your code in viewcontroller1 looks like this

```
-(IBAction)button; {
 ViewController2 *viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
 viewcontroller2.textToShow = ......;
 //show view of your viewcontroller2
 // e.g.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller2 animated:YES];
 }
```

And your viewcontroller2 header file(ViewController2.h)

```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *testToShow;
```

you viewController2 implementation file (Viewcontroller2.m)

```
@synthesize textToShow;
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
     UILabel *label = UILabel aloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
     [self.view addSubview:label];
     label.text = self.textToShow;
 }
```

Comment: I use a button to change view controllers

Comment: I understand what you say but I don't understand that textToShow code can I add my if else code there which is written at the main question area ?

Comment: You can write your if else code block in action method (-(IBAction)button) like you did in your question and set viewcontroller2.textToShow, which text you want.

Comment: when I use this code and change the view controller names Xcode says that its not defined so I add the import.viewcontroller2 to the top but this time when I insert my code it says that labels are not defined but they are defined at viewcontroller2.h and that was imported too...

Comment: in all of my projects I had that not define problem so I solved most of them by importing the other view controllers.h to the top am I doing right ?

Comment: by the way your nickname is my consins name : )

Comment: Xcode gives undeclared identifier for the label I imported theviewcontroller2.h to the top but still ı have this error why ?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to put *. Please check if you have typed correctly.

Comment: No I put it but I see navigation controller at the code do I need to use navigation controller at the storyboard for my view controllers ?

Comment: Maybe you should look at this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use protocol

1) creat protocol in viewcontroller1.h like this

```
@protocol ViewController1Delegate <NSObject>

- (void)dealWithButton1;

@end
```

2) added delegate.in viewcontroller1.h

```
@interface viewcontroller1 : XXXXX
{
    id<ViewController1Delegate> delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<ViewController1Delegate> delegate;

@end
```

3) added synthesize in viewcontroller1.m

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

4) deal with button sender

```
-(IBAction)button
{
    [delegate dealWithButton1];
}
```

5) deal with viewcontroller2.h

```
@interface viewcontroller2 : XXXXX<ViewController1Delegate>
{
    viewcontroller1 *vc1 ;
}
```

6) binding the delegate in viewcontroller2.m

```
vc1.delegate = self;
```

7) achieve the delegate in viewcontroller2.m

```
- (void)dealWithButton1
{
int random_num;
random_num = (arc4random() % 5 - 1) + 1;
if (random_num == 1)
{ 
    label.text = @"hello1";    
}
else if (random_num == 2)
    label.text = @"hello2";
else if (random_num == 3)
    label.text = @"hello3";
else if (random_num == 4)
    label.text = @"hello4";
}
```

Comment: I will do this step by step and share the results with you right now

Comment: good luck. i think you should learn something about the protocol

Comment: I did it step by step and it seems to me the solution but I got many errors I pasted everything you wrote in the correct place...

Lets solve it step by step...

interface viewcontroller1 : XXXXX

I wrote uiviewcontroller instead of XXX but I think that was wrong what should I do ?

Comment: oke I solved all problems in h file but @synthesize delegate; gives me an error where should I put this at the top at the bottom or elsewhere

Comment: ...put it on the top of all you methods.and below the @implementation viewcontroller2

Comment: as far as I know synthesis has to be placed at inside the implementation and at the top but it didn't work any ideas ?
error: existing ivar'delegate' for property 'delegate with assign attribute must be __unsafe untrained

Comment: I guess that I am putting it to the right place but cause when I try to write it Xcode shows the same(writing help) I receive the error above what should ı do pls help me

Comment: Also what about those XXXX maybe that causes the problem what should ı write there ?